# 'float' object has no attribute 'replace' IP ADRESS

Tags: python, object, replace, attributes

I want to omet point from the IP address. For example: converting 127.0.0.1 to 127001
 for that I make this mini function:

```
for i in range(len(pos_data['c_ip'])):
e = pos_data['c_ip'][i].replace('.','')
pos_data['c_ip'][i] = int(e)
```

But I get this error:

'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Any help please

Comment: You are trying to replace dots in Float, convert it to string and replace dots

Answer (score 1):

`pos_data['c_ip'][i]` return `float` value, if you want to remove the `.` you need to cast is to `str`

```
e = str(pos_data['c_ip'][i]).replace('.', '')
```

However, instead of iterating over the IP char by char just remove all `.` from the original `str`

```
e = pos_data['c_ip'].replace('.', '')
```

Comment: Thks Guy for your reponse.

When I put this correction, I get new error :

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'replace'

Any idea please ?